# Allow oembed tag in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.x

I want to put oembed tags into the ckeditor RTE of TYPO3. This way I want to put social post like instagram, facebook or twitter into some news article (in the middle of some text).

For this purpose I have activated the embed plugins of ckeditor and put the `oembed` tag under `processing` in `allowedTags`. I also defined the oembed tag in the constants for `styles.content.allowTags`.

**Here my yaml:**

```
imports:
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Processing.yaml" }
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Base.yaml" }
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Plugins.yaml" }

editor:
    config:
        contentsCss: "EXT:mysitepackage/Resources/Public/Css/rte.css"

        stylesSet:
            - { name: "Lead", element: "p", attributes: { 'class': 'lead' } }

        toolbarGroups:
            - { name: styles, groups: [ format, styles ] }
            - { name: basicstyles, groups: [ basicstyles ] }
            - { name: paragraph, groups: [ list, indent, blocks, align ] }
            - "/"
            - { name: links, groups: [ links ] }
            - { name: clipboard, groups: [ clipboard, cleanup, undo ] }
            - { name: editing, groups: [ spellchecker ] }
            - { name: insert, groups: [ insert ] }
            - { name: tools, groups: [ table, specialchar ] }
            - { name: document, groups: [ mode ] }

        format_tags: "p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;pre"

        justifyClasses:
            - text-left
            - text-center
            - text-right
            - text-justify

        extraPlugins:
            - justify
            - embedsemantic
            - autoembed

        removePlugins:
            - image

        removeButtons:
            - Anchor
            - Underline
            - Strike

        autoEmbedWidget: "embedsemantic"
        embed_provider: "https://my.iframely.instance/oembed?url={url}&callback={callback}"

        extraAllowedContent: '*(*)[data-*]; oembed'

processing:
    allowTags:
        - oembed
```

**This row in the constants:**

```
styles.content.allowTags := addToList(oembed)
```

I'm now able to put the oembed into the RTE and its displayed teaser of the social post. After saving the content the `oembed` tag is replaced by a `p` tag

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the html source in ckeditor before and after it is changed?

Comment: Before: `<oembed>[URL OF POST]</oembed>` after: `<p>[URL OF POST]</p>`

Comment: If it does not eat the processing settings in the YML, does it eat the regular TSconfig for RTE in addition? Like `RTE.default.proc.allowTags = oembed`

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, if something gets replaced with something else (especially the p tag), chances are high it is related to the [Advanced content filter](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_acf.html).

I can't pinpoint the error in your config, but have you tried disabeling ACF completely? (see [allowedContent](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#allowedContent))

```
allowedContent = true;
(and remove the extraAllowedContent)
```

If that works, don't leave it like that (see [security best practices](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_best_practices.html)), but work your way through to find the correct setting.

Maybe explicitly add  the wildcard attributes in the extraAllowedContent:

```
extraAllowedContent: '*(*)[data-*]; oembed(*){*}[*];'
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. Maybe the TYPO3 CMS is filtering that out.